# WCF service not running on other devices except server

Tags: c#, android-studio, wcf, service

I have WCF service which runs fine on my server machine using IP, it was working on client side(android studio) but suddenly it stopped working, I tried all solutions from internet but nothing seems to help, Service is sill working on Server browser/Postman.

Here's my web.config file if it is required:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration>

<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WcfService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WCFService.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="myWeb" contract="WcfService.IService1">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myWeb">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFService.Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
 <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>

 </system.webServer>

 </configuration>
```

Also my Firewall is disabled completely.
When I ping service from mobile or other pc it gives error:
 This site can't be reached.
 Err_Address_Unreachable

Comment: What mean "Service still.working on server" if you say you can't reach It ? From whitch device you try ? Whitch address have you try (localhost)? What mean "suddently It stopper working"?

Comment: Still working on server means if I try it on my server's browser or Postman it works fine.
I tried to ping it from another pc and Samsung mobile device(which btw it was working on earlier) on both browser and client application.
The Address: http://192.168.100.110:80/WcfService/Service1.svc/getColors
Suddenly stopped working means it was working fine earlier on mobile/client/other browsers, now it's not. I haven't made any changes to server.

Comment: Check the firewall is is restarted on reboot and check also the antivir pgm on your machine

Comment: Firewall is off, I've been furiously checking it time to time cause all answers suggested so. also there are no antivirus programs installed on my machine.

Comment: The ip is correct ? Maybe the DHCP have assigned you another ? Both PCs MUST be on the SAME lan, check also the IP of the _other PC_ .

Comment: IP is correct as of I took it from cmd->ipconfig
IDK how do you check DHCP ip?
Both pcs are on same client. 
Also if I check ipconfig on other pcs they all give different IPs despite connected to same WiFi but my senior told me it's fine.

Comment: I don't known your LAN and routes but for simple scenario most of the time different IPs == Different Lans. Try to ping the `client` from the `server` I think you can't.

Comment: Also this is the error I get in client Android studio application:
 Error :com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.100.110 (port 80) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)

Answer (score 0):

First, can you call the service successfully from the other computer in the same LAN?
Second, what is the IP of your mobile device?
Finally, have you tried to restart your router/switch device in the current LAN? It is possible that there is something wrong with the router device which provides the Addressing function.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: No, I can't now, (it was working earlier but not now).
IP is changed but it's connected on same LAN.
Yes, I've tried to restart my router.

Comment: Is this the first answer?  If indeed,  can you Ping the server successfully from the other computer in the same LAN? Besides, if the IP is changed, please use the latest IP.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer's firewall is disabled check if your router has firewall and disable it.